# How to ignore some statements in Javascript code coverage when using lcov and istanbul?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, istanbul, lcov

How is it possible to make sonarqube take into account directives found in code comments? There is a page on Istanbul describing how to ignore some branches using comments like this

```
/* istanbul ignore if  */
if (hardToReproduceError)) {
    return callback(hardToReproduceError);
}
```

(see https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md)

It works well into HTML reports generated by Istanbul but it does not work with Sonarqube.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is not supported by the SonarQube platform, so currently it is not possible to ignore reported uncovered line.